# update table using Label.Text

Tags: asp.net

A simple update operation is throwing an error like "incorrect syntax near '('". My code is below.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        string insCmd = "update Reg set (DateOfBirth,Experience)=@DateOfBirth,@Experience where UserName='"+Label3.Text+"'";
        SqlCommand insertUser = new SqlCommand(insCmd, con);
        insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Experience",TextBoxex.Text);
        insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth",TextBoxdob.Text);
        try
        {
            insertUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");
        }
```

Comment: Testing your SQL statement against a DBMS before embedding in your project would be a glorious idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the bracket from column name around `Set` like this:

```
string insCmd = "update Reg set DateOfBirth=@DateOfBirth where UserName='"+Label3.Text+"'";
```